# Joomla 1.5 Module Outputting return Statement

Tags: php, joomla, module, joomla1.5

I am building a Joomla module which will eventually pull data from an external data source. Right now while I learn, I set it to simply print the string "This bit works correctly" to the module position. However, I have been having problems getting it to work correctly. Here is my code:

mod_ucr.php:

```
<?php
/**
* UniversalContentRepository Module Entry Point
* 
* @package    UniversalContentRepository
* @subpackage Modules
*/

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php' );
$helper = new modUCRHelper();
$content = $helper->getSnippetContent();
require( JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath( 'mod_ucr' ) );
?>
```

mod_ucr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install type="module" version="1.5.0">
    <name>Universal Content Repository</name>
    <author>Brendon Dugan</author>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <description>A module to allow the insertion of UCR Snippets into a Joomla site.</description>
    <files>
        <filename>mod_ucr.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_ucr">mod_ucr.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <params>
    </params>
</install>
```

helper.php:

```
<?php
class modUCRHelper
{
    function __construct(){

    }


    public function getSnippetContent($id = 0){
        $content = "This bit works correctly, ID = $id";
        return $content;
    }
}
?>
```

tmpl/default.php:

```
<?php // no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
echo $content; 
?>
```

Here we set the variable $content to be the output of the getSnippetContent() method of the helper class. This method is currently:

```
function getSnippetContent($id = 0){
    $output = "This bit works correctly";
    return $output;
}
```

Which simply outputs the string I want to print. In my template, I should be able to echo content like this:

```
<?php // no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
echo $content; 
?>
```

But what the module outputs instead is

```
"This bit works correctlyThis bit works correctly"
```

If I comment out the echo statement, the string is still echoed once, suggesting that the return statement itself is echoing.

I adapted my code from the "Hello World!" example located [in the Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5). Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you post all your (I believe 4) files for the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Core joomla code for displaying module

```
$content = '';
ob_start();
require $path;
$module->content = ob_get_contents().$content;
ob_end_clean();
```

It uses the $content variable itself. And your module is changing the value of $content. One output is from your module and another is due to this joomla code. It appends the content of your module to $content variable (which has been changed in your module).

So do not use $content variable in you code.

Comment: That fixed it! I didn't see anything about that in Joomla's documentation... are there other undocumented pitfalls that you are able to forewarn me about?

Comment: I also didn't know that before, just came to know when i was looking for solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is not echoing.

An idea is to add more information to your function.
Try adding the ID to the output, like so

```
function getSnippetContent($id = 0){
    $output = "This bit works correctly. ID=" .$id ."<br>";
    return $output;
}
```

and see if that triggers any ideas. Maybe you added the module twice?

Comment: Adding the ID to the output does print the id to the screen with the output, but does not fix the problem. Commenting out the echo statement however, does alter the output to print only once. The absence of an echo statement plus the presence of output suggests that the return statement is echoing.

Comment: Search in your code for `getSnippetContent`. What do you find?

Comment: The entire project consists of a total of less than 10 lines of actual code. Searching for getSnippetContent returns the function definition, and the single time it is called to assign its output to the $content variable.